# Problem with reloadComponent

Tags: iphone, components, uipickerview, reload

I have a UIPickerView with 2 components.
And I have 2 Core Data entities, where one has a relationship one-to-many to the second one.

I've implemented this 4 delegate functions:

```
- numberOfComponentsInPicker
- numberOfRowsInComponent
- titleForRow:forComponent
- didSelectRow:inComponent
```

where the last one is as:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

 if (component == 0){
    [thePickerView reloadComponent:1];
 }
}
```

^ The view loads with data. But when it runs it hangs on this one.  I understand it's supposed to load the second component, but I don't know if it's missing something else, or another method needs to be implemented.

What is really going on when I call `reloadComponent` ? And how can I load the second column (component) with other data after user has selected the first column (component)?

Comment: Is it going into an infinite loop calling pickerView::: ?  It seems like what you're doing should work.

Comment: yeah, got it working, had a wrong IF in another function.  I'll delete the question in a few hours, after your read this :P

Answer (score 0):

apart from connect delegate and data souce

make sure u connect the thePickerView to the IBOUTLET pickerview at the IB